# VB6 program using ODBC will not run in Win7 64

Tags: mysql, windows-7, vb6, odbc

I have an old VB6 program that uses a MySQL 4.07 database.  It was developed on my Win XP 64 bit machine. It works fine on my Win XP 64 machine and it works fine on my Win7 64 bit machine.  But when one of our users tries to run it on their Win7 64 machine, it fails with

```
    "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".
```

What is odd is that they have installed the ODBC drivers and have them in SysWOW64 and system32.

The following code is executed in Form_Load and is more than likely where the error occurs (note that the 32 bit driver is for NT Server 2.5 and the 64 bit one is a newer version.):

```
    If IsHost64Bit() = True Then
        mstrConnString = "driver=MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver;server=mysqleng;database=engprogs;port=3306;UID=user;PWD=########"
    Else
        mstrConnString = "driver=MySQL;server=mysqleng;database=engprogs;port=3306;UID=user;PWD=########"
    End If

    Set ADOCn = New ADODB.Connection
    ADOCn.ConnectionString = mstrConnString
    ADOCn.Open mstrConnString
```

I've checked the properties of odbcad32.exe inside SysWOW64 and the driver tab shows MySQL ODBC 3.51 on the users machines!

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: We have three legacy VB6 applications and we have found that we need to use the 32 Bit ODBC to connect to our databases.

Comment: Mark, did you install the 32bit ODBC driver on a 64bit machine?

Comment: Are you having to add "_32" to the 32 bit user DSNs and "_64" to the 64bit user DSNs using odbcad32.exe?

Comment: No we use an older Wise Installer application to create the MSI and the MSI creates the 32 ODBC DSN for us.

Comment: Mark, I finally got VB6 installed on my Win7 64.  I ignored the compatibility warnings and it works fine as far as I can tell.  So now I was able to single step thru the code and discovered that "IsHost64Bit()" was not working properly in Win7 64!  It was therefore loading the "mstrConnString" from the 32 bit.  That is why it was failing when the program starts.  So my new task is to fix "IsHost64Bit()".  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Great job! I am glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion with Mark Kram led me to try and install VB6 on the Win7 64 bit computer. During the install I ignored the compatibility warnings. It installed and works fine as far as I can tell. Because of that I was able to single step thru the code and discovered that "IsHost64Bit()" was not working properly in Win7 64! The "IsHost64Bit()" routine was indicating that the 64 bit computer was 32 bit! It was therefore loading the "mstrConnString" from the 32 bit. That is why it was failing when the program starts.

"IsHost64Bit()" requires:

```
Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcess Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function IsWow64Process Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal hProc As Long, ByRef bWow64Process As Boolean) As Long
```

The "IsHost64Bit()" routine:

```
Public Function IsHost64Bit() As Boolean
Dim handle As Long
Dim is64Bit As Boolean

' Assume initially that this is not a WOW64 process
is64Bit = False

' Then try to prove that wrong by attempting to load the
' IsWow64Process function dynamically
handle = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), "IsWow64Process")

' The function exists, so call it
If handle <> 0 Then
    IsWow64Process GetCurrentProcess(), is64Bit
End If

' Return the value
IsHost64Bit = is64Bit
End Function
```

I replaced "IsHost64Bit()" with:

```
Dim wmi, prc
Dim prcOS As String

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\")
For Each prc In wmi.execQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
  Debug.Print prc.Name, "Bit Sizes - ADDR:"; prc.AddressWidth, "DATA:"; prc.DataWidth
  prcOS = Str(prc.DataWidth)
Next
```

And the Form_Load routine now correctly checks for 64 bit as follows:

```
If prcOS = " 64" Then
    mstrConnString = "driver=MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver;server=mysqleng;database=engprogs;port=3306;UID=user;PWD=########"
Else
    mstrConnString = "driver=MySQL;server=mysqleng;database=engprogs;port=3306;UID=user;PWD=########"
End If

Set ADOCn = New ADODB.Connection
ADOCn.ConnectionString = mstrConnString
ADOCn.Open mstrConnString
```

Answer (score 0):

First, download the MySQL ODBC connector (the current version)

Remove your previous MySQL ODBC connector

Install the new version with all the options

This worked for me

The 32 bit version also runs on a 64 bit machine.